# Warning: Unresponsive Script Firefox - CARTO

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cartodb

I am using CARTO sql api to fetch latitude and longitude. Below is the code snippet am using to accomplish this. Whenever I load the page, the coordinates are printed in the console but I get a popup saying Warning: Unresponsive Script (see img). What could be the problem.

`var coordSql = 'https://myusername.carto.com/api/v2/sql/?q=SELECT latitude, longitude FROM db_table’
    $.getJSON(coordSql, function(data) {
      $.each(data.rows, function(key, val) {
        //
        if(data.rows){
          var coordinates = [];
          for(var i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++){
            coordinates.push([data.rows[i]['latitude'], data.rows[i]['longitude']])
          }
          console.log(coordinates);
        }
      });
    });`